# Cannot compile .obj file into .exe... LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python34.lib'

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a python program into a standalone without bundling. So far I have:

- converted a script file into a .c file with Cython
- converted the .c file into a .obj file using the MVSC compiler

My problem is the completing the last step:

- converting the .obj file into a .exe

I've used the following DOS commands:

```
@echo off
:: Load compilation environment
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

:: Invoke compiler with any options passed to this batch file
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe %*

:: call the MVSC compiler
cl /c main.c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I"c:\Python34\include" 
-Ic:\Python34\PC /main.c /link /OUT:"main.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE 
/MACHINE:X86 /LIBPATH:"c:\Python34\libs" /LIBPATH:"c:\Python34\PCbuild"

:: create main.exe out of main.obj
cl main.obj -o main.exe
```

I get the following error:

```
/out:main.exe
/out:main.exe
main.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python34.lib'
```

Comment: Looks like the error came from the final `cl`.  You need to specify the `/LIBPATH` there as well.  Not an answer, because I cannot test it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution later. Right now, I am downgrading to 2.X and using pyinstall.